# JQuery- append element's current html to element's new child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my HTML dynamically based on some conditions in javascript.
I have following HTML structure:

```
<div class="videoInfo">
    <h4>My Title</h4>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <p>My description</p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

After running my script, I want the HTML like this:

```
<div class="videoInfo">
    <div class="videoInfoShadow"></div>
    <div class="videoInfoInner">
        <h4>My Title</h4>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <p>My description</p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can do this with the following code:

```
 var videoInfoHtml = $(".videoInfo").html();
 $(".videoInfo").html("");
 $(".videoInfo").append('<div class="videoInfoShadow">');
 $(".videoInfo").append('<div class="videoInfoInner">');
 $(".videoInfoInner").html(videoInfoHtml);
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML instead of HAML?

Comment: Probably something like `$('.videoInfo').wrapInner('<div class="videoInfoInner"></div>').prepend('<div class="videoInfoShadow"></div>')` because that way, you just move nodes around (no node to html-string convert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the contents of your 'videoInfo' DIV with the 'videoInfoInner' DIV you've created and stick the new 'videoInfoShadow' DIV in front of it:

```
var videoInfo = $('.videoInfo');
videoInfo.wrapInner($(document.createElement('div')).addClass('videoInfoInner'));
videoInfo.prepend($(document.createElement('div')).addClass('videoInfoShadow'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mB6g3/1/)

Comment: Are you sure that this works? `html()` returns a string not a jquery object, so there is no `wrap` method.

Comment: It works now.  (See fiddle.) Sorry, was editing when you commented.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you found the answer helpful, please feel free to accept and, when you have sufficient rep, upvote it.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah!I'll definately do that.